# what type of regression will fit my data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to test to see if BMI is affected by some variables in three specific states, KY,CO,NY, such as Marital status, Race, Age, Exercise in the last 30 days, Sleep amount at night, Education level. Some of the values for the data has more than 2 variables, for example Marital status has values, 1 = married, 2 = divorced, 3= widowed, 4 = seperated an so on. I ran a simple regression and trie to filter for the three states, but the rsults I got are not making sense.

Here is the summary statistics.

```
Call:
lm(formula = BMI ~ PHYSHLTH + SLEPTIM1 + Exercise + MARITAL + 
    EDUCA + RACE, data = X)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2375.0  -421.0   -95.4   309.1  6893.2 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2971.29540    7.24185 410.295  < 2e-16 ***
PHYSHLTH      -1.44822    0.03017 -48.005  < 2e-16 ***
SLEPTIM1      -1.20337    0.14361  -8.379  < 2e-16 ***
Exercise     143.97687    2.21517  64.996  < 2e-16 ***
MARITAL      -15.19189    0.60613 -25.064  < 2e-16 ***
EDUCA        -37.21213    1.05738 -35.193  < 2e-16 ***
RACE           3.25357    0.45323   7.179 7.06e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 629.3 on 360592 degrees of freedom
  (41359 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.02753,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02751 
F-statistic:  1701 on 6 and 360592 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Please explain *how* the results do "not make sense."